# Find value using python regex in a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex

In this example I need salt value in both strings.

```
string = 'SHA-224(Salt len: 20)'

string2 = '# Salt len: 0' 
 
pattern = re.compile(r'^(#\s)?((SHA-\d+)?\(?Salt len: \d+\)?)') 
 
result = pattern.search(string)  

result2 = pattern.search(string2)

print(result)

print(result2)
```

**Expected output**:
`20`
`0`

please help me guys

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/aJMiGc/1) working for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a simpler pattern that will match `Salt len:`, spaces and then captures any amount of digits:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'\bSalt len: (\d+)')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yhNcch/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `Salt len:`  - a string
- `(\d+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more digits

When using in Python, check for a match first:

```
result = pattern.search(string)
```

Then, check if there was a match, and if yes, extract Group 1 value.

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##RY0/C8IwFMT3fIoHDklQS61OhQ5u7h2tQ62vNtAm4eUV9NPH/hF6y8Hxuzv/5c7Zc4xm8I4YCAXjhwMUcJfl7XrMsosq656hR5tDlmp5ALmDLUrlQ/iaGclOJcKkcYM3PSqS1XPDVPXaa6lBtI5gvgBjFw@5gEmEYZzYAv5bScCamk7NiF4I0/6htTDLk7Gs1jR5kxu9OmktYvwB):

```
import re
texts = ['SHA-224(Salt len: 20)', '# Salt len: 0']
pattern = re.compile(r'\bSalt len: (\d+)') 
for text in texts:
    result = pattern.search(text)
    if result:
        print(result.group(1))
```